# Integer round in java

Tags: java

In Java, I want to round up to the closest integer value eliminating the last 2 digits

from 54321 ->  54300 or 8765 -> 8800

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you want to round 8550 to 8600, just use:

```
int rounded = ((original + 50) / 100) * 100;
```

The division will just truncate, but the previous addition will bias that truncation to give an overall round-up effect.

EDIT: As noted by Peter, you need to consider negative numbers separately, and probably subtract 50 instead of adding it.

Comment: +1: For negative numbers you might want to subtract the same value. Otherwise -149 would be "rounded" to 0.

Comment: e.g. `int rounded = (original > 0 ? original + 50 : original - 50) / 100 * 100;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `(int)Math.round(number/100f)*100;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulo operator (%). Calculate the value modulo 100. This is a value between 0 and 99 (the last 2 digits). Then decide if you have to round up or down.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
float num = 8765 * 1;
System.out.println(Math.round(num / 100) * 100);
```